# ngx-datatable expand rows by default based on property

Tags: angular, datatable, ngx-datatable

I would like to use a value from my data (open) which will determine if a row will be expanded or not on page load.

```
// sample data

{
 open: true,
 address: {
  city: Atlanta,
  state: Ga
 }
}
```

Looking at the expand features it looks like it's only based on a toggle action.

Seems like it should be a property when defining the row details template but it's not obvious to me.

```
    <!-- Row Detail Template -->
    <ngx-datatable-row-detail [rowHeight]="100" #myDetailRow (toggle)="onDetailToggle($event)">
      <ng-template let-row="row" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-row-detail-template>
        <div style="padding-left:35px;">
          <div><strong>Address</strong></div>
          <div>{{row.address.city}}, {{row.address.state}}</div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-row-detail>
```

In the in the sample `row-detail.component.ts` the `expanded: any = {};` prop but it doesn't appear to have any effect if I remove it or try to populate it with some data. The toggle event doesn't appear to use that prop either. Not sure what it is used for...

Comment: Did you find a solution to achieve that?

Comment: I did not. I've actually changed jobs since that project so I haven't looked at it for some time.

Comment: I have the same problem. 
The expanded: any = {}; is not used at all, like you already found out.